# Switch from seconds to Timedelta by column with specific name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

Let it be the following python pandas dataframe:

| other | value | time_UK | total_time_UK | color | counter_time_UK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 392 | idk | 0 | 0 | red | 8393283 |
| 2393 | odp | 930233 | 23423423 | blue | 322332 |
| 392 | kfl | 0 | 0 | red | 0 |
| 323 | bcn | 783732 | 32423 | green | 42332 |
| 9695 | uie | 0 | 0 | red | 3423283 |
| 111 | xas | 0 | 3423323 | blue | 322 |

I would like for the columns containing the string `time_UK`, to convert their values in seconds to TimeDelta and if its value is 0 to NaT.

| other | value | time_UK | total_time_UK | color | counter_time_UK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 392 | idk | NaT | NaT | red | pd.to_timedelta(8393283) |
| 2393 | odp | pd.to_timedelta(930233) | pd.to_timedelta(23423423) | blue | pd.to_timedelta(322332) |
| 392 | kfl | NaT | NaT | red | NaT |
| 323 | bcn | pd.to_timedelta(783732) | pd.to_timedelta(32423) | green | pd.to_timedelta(42332) |
| 9695 | uie | NaT | NaT | red | pd.to_timedelta(3423283) |
| 111 | xas | NaT | pd.to_timedelta(3423323) | blue | pd.to_timedelta(322) |

Right now Im using next code:

```
    # Sets the 0 second values to NaT    
    df.loc[df['time_UK'] == 0.0, 'time_UK'] = pd.NaT
    
    # Converts seconds to TimeDelta type
    df['time_UK'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time_UK'], unit='s')
```

I am grateful for the help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for DataFrame `df1` by columns name `time_UK`, convert to floats, replace `0` by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with convert all columns to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df1 = df.filter(like='time_UK').astype(float)
df[df1.columns] = df1.mask(df1.eq(0)).apply(pd.to_timedelta, unit='s')
print (df)
   other value          time_UK     total_time_UK  color  counter_time_UK
0    392   idk              NaT               NaT    red 97 days 03:28:03
1   2393   odp 10 days 18:23:53 271 days 02:30:23   blue  3 days 17:32:12
2    392   kfl              NaT               NaT    red              NaT
3    323   bcn  9 days 01:42:12   0 days 09:00:23  green  0 days 11:45:32
4   9695   uie              NaT               NaT    red 39 days 14:54:43
5    111   xas              NaT  39 days 14:55:23   blue  0 days 00:05:22
```

Comment: I get this error: 
TypeError: invalid type promotion

Comment: @Carola - Can you test now?

Comment: Now, I get other error ->  assert mask.dtype == bool, mask.dtype AssertionError: object

Comment: @Carola - if use only `df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].eq(0))` it working - replace 0 to `NaN`s ?

Comment: No, therein lies the error. But it does work: ```df[cols].eq(0)```

Comment: @Carola - what is `print (df['time_UK'].head().tolist())` ?

Comment: this ```[3840.0, 0.0, 0.0, 19687200.0, 84000.0]```

Comment: It looks good, if use `df[cols].mask(df[cols].eq(0))` it working? Or need `df[cols].astype(float).mask(df[cols].astype(float).eq(0))` ?

Comment: The second solution adding astype float works!

Comment: @Carola - Super, answer was edited.